# Nested flux in Java 8 reactive streams

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux

I have 3 return flux statements, all nested one within another like below :-
I have 3 items in 3 repositories - > reactiveRepo1,2,3

will the below snippet return 27 different apples ?

```
private Flux<Apple> method() {
    Apple A = new Apple(); 
    return reactiveRepo1.findAll()
        .flatMap(item -> {
            A.setProp1(item.getSomething())
            return reactvieRepo2.findAll()
                .flatMap(item2 -> {
                    A.setProp2("item.getSomething2()")
                    return reactiveRepo3.findAll()
                        .flatMap(item3 -> { 
                            A.setProp3("item.getSomething3()");
                            return A;
                        });
                });
         });

}
```

Comment: Fluxes are pipelines, not loops. Also, 3^3  = 27.

Comment: Correction made. So how do i use looping in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
private Flux<Apple> method() {
    return Flux.zip(Array.asList(
        reactiveRepo1.findAll(),
        reactvieRepo2.findAll(),
        reactiveRepo3.findAll()),
        arrayReturnValues -> {

            ...

        }
    );
}
```

where *arrayReturnValues* is an array which contains all values retrieved from all repository. In the ... you have to write a function that handle return values

Comment: So, in all ill have 9 values ?

Comment: Yes, you will have an array of 9 elements of Object

Comment: i was looking for 3^3 = 27 , i.e with all possible combinations